# Impersonal Construction with Se vs Commands?

Tags: verbo-pronominal, oraciones-impersonales

Should sentences using the Impersonal Construction with `se` be translated / read as commands? i.e. should `se nada en la piscina y el océano` be translated/read as "Swim in the pool and ocean" or "They swim in the pool and ocean?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no.

That said, the impersonal *se* construction can be best translated as *one does something* which, like in English, can be used as a sort of psuedo-imperative in the sense that you're emphasizing that one ought do something in some particular way:

- *En mi casa, no se habla de política*
  <sup>One does not talk politics in my house</sup>

Obviously, context will be important.  The sign a store door that says *Se habla español* probably means more likely "Spanish is spoken here", although one could equally envision a person in a store yelling at a non-Spanish speaker effectively telling them to speak Spanish by saying *Aquí se habla español* (which contextually means more likely "One ought to speak Spanish here [and not the other language]")

Answer (score 0):

The impersonal `se` can't be translated as a command, but I wouldn't have translated as you did in your example with a "they" (after all, is *impersonal*).

> **They** swim in the pool and ocean

would be " **Ellos** nadan en la piscina y en el océano.

> Swim in the pool and ocean

Could be read as a command or invitation: "Nada en la piscina o en el océano, donde quieras"; "Nada en la piscina o en el océano, pero no en el río".

Translating the impersonal `se` could be tricky regarding the pronoun.

> Se hacen trajes; Se hacen arreglos

Could be translated as "**We** make suits; **We** fix clothing".

> Se duerme de noche y se trabaja de día

Could be translated as "You/We sleep at night and work at day", but definitely I wouldn't have used "They" to convey the generality of the *impersonal*.